# API/JSON Connection

Tags: python

I am trying to connect to an API so I can grab data to use in some spatial analytics. This is my first program in Python. I have been able to connect to the API and can grab the fields i need from the resulting JSON file(s).

My main issue is actually combining it all together. As it stands now I have two options

- Generate separate arrays for each "column" i.e. an array for lat and an array for long, and then combine it into a table at the end or
- Generate one array with all columns in it and then split by "row".

The goal is to CSV this and upload to tableau. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I haven't explained myself clearly, apologies!

This example code below is currently following option 2, however I am stuck at splitting by row. I can switch to option 1 by changing the data array it appends.

Does anyone have any suggestions or guidance?

http://pastebin.com/EgD83UUD

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using python 2 or python 3?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending everything into a single array like you are currently, if you instead store all values of one iteration into an array and append that to another array you can simply convert that two-dimensional array into a csv file directly using the csv module.

**this solution works for python 3.x**

Note: you have to add a valid api key for API_KEY in the code below

```
import requests
import json
import csv

from pprint import pprint

#DEFINING PAGE DATA GRAB FUNCTION
def recordloop(jra):
    i = 0
    for entry in jra:
        data=[]
        try:
            data.append(jra[i]['aboutId'])
        except:
            data.append('')
        try:
            data.append(jra[i]['businessInfo']['abn'])
        except:
            data.append('')
        try:
            data.append(jra[i]['businessInfo']['dateEstablished'])
        except:
            data.append('')
        try:
            data.append(jra[i]['businessInfo']['numberOfEmployees'])
        except:
            data.append('')
        try:
            data.append(jra[i]['name'])
        except:
            data.append('')
        try:
            data.append(jra[i]['lastUpdated'])
        except:
            data.append('')
        try:
            data.append(jra[i]['primaryAddress']['addressLine'])
        except:
            data.append('')
        try:
            data.append(jra[i]['primaryAddress']['suburb'])
        except:
            data.append('')
        try:
            data.append(jra[i]['primaryAddress']['postcode'])
        except:
            data.append('')
        try:
            data.append(jra[i]['primaryAddress']['state'])
        except:
            data.append('')
        try:
            data.append(jra[i]['primaryAddress']['latitude'])
        except:
            data.append('')
        try:
            data.append(jra[i]['primaryAddress']['longitude'])
        except:
            data.append('')
        i=i+1

        data_copy = data[:]
        list_data.append(data_copy)
    return;

#LOOPING THROUGH PAGES
list_data = []
j=1
while (j<3):
    r  = requests.get("http://api.sensis.com.au/v1/test/search?query=veterinarian&rows=50&page="+str(j)+"&key=API_KEY")
    jr = json.loads(r.text)
    jra=jr['results']
    recordloop(jra)
    j=j+1


with open("output.csv", "w", newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(list_data)
```

**Python 2 solution:**

replace "w" with "wb"

**Untested**

```
with open("output.csv", "wb", newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(list_data)
```

Comment: Thank-you very much Danoram. Works perfectly. I appreciate the help!